# Find which range a cell belongs to

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with columns A and B populated with numbers, a la:

```
1   12
13  20
21  30
31  35
```

This is just as an example, in reality A and B are columns of length 50ish.

In this example, I have another column with values in it between 1 and 30.  I want to write a function that returns which range it is between.  Perhaps a 1 if it is between the first range (1-12) 2 between the second (13-20) etc.

This is the way the data was presented to me, if it needs to be re-arranged so be it.

Does anyone know any functions that would be useful to solve this problem?  I have read that nested if statements are limited to 7 "if's" so I would need to write out a bunch of them.

Thanks folks.

Comment: You can use a lookup function such as MATCH() for this: it has options for dealing with inexact matches as long as your data is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim has said, [=MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) looks most suitable, without its optional third parameter, so that it “finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value.” Hence the upper bounds (right-hand column in your question) are not required for this formula. The numbers returned are the relative positions of the ‘match’ in the selected array. If your “*another column with values in it between 1 and 30*” is say C and starts in Row2 then `=MATCH(C2,A:A)` copied down is a generalisation that will only return 1, 2, 3 if the population of A:B starts in Row1. In other words, if the `1` in A is say in Row3 then I’d recommend:

```
=MATCH(C2,A$3:A$6)
```

copied down to suit.
The last number in A (ie `31`) can be anything as long as it is more than the upper bound of your “*between 1 and 30*”.